# Opening icloud event (created using ical.net) on outlook client shows Free/busy status as "Out off office" instead of busy

Tags: outlook, icalendar, ical-dotnet

```
Nuget version: Ical.Net 2.2.30
observed behavior: Status sets as OOF
expected behavior: Status should set as BUSY

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iCal 5.0.2//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Test
DTEND:20170324T104500Z
DTSTAMP:20170324T093907Z
DTSTART:20170324T103000Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:Confirmed
SUMMARY:Test
UID:FC97A241-EC79-4848-8842-3920C58EE520
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Event created fine, busy time retrieved fine but if I have my icloud account on my outlook client it shows status as OOF instead of busy.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution.

Solution :Need to add X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS property manually.

```
event.AddProperty("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS", "BUSY");
```

Thanks!